# OnTriggerEnter is fired each frame when object is in collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have enemy object which fire `OnTriggerEnter()` on BoxCollider each frame when this object is in this BoxCollider. I noticed that when I turn off NavMeshAgent on enemy object then everything is ok - `OnTriggerEnter()` is fired only once. 
Does anyone knows what should I do with it?

Comment: what is NavMeshAgent?

Comment: @Cenkisabi - Unity3D documentation says:
"_This component is attached to a mobile character in the game to allow it to navigate the scene using the NavMesh. See the Navigation section of the manual for further details._"

Copied from [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent.html).